# single test calling multiple times in Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am reading the inputs like testname, expected result, parameters from xml file and depends on inputs(testname), calling the respective testmethod multiple times. for example

```
public void test_calc()  throws Exception{
    ............
    .......
    if(testName.equalsIgnoreCase("addition")){                
        addition(table, expectedResult);                             
    }
    else if(testName.equalsIgnoreCase("multiplication")){           
        multiplication(table, expectedResult);                
    }

    else if(testName.equalsIgnoreCase("substraction")){
        substraction(table, expectedResult);    
    }
```

I am calling same method multiple times depends on XML inputs. I am using ANT to run this Junit tests and all tests are executed correctly.But in the report it showing as single test with testname **test_calc** not the addition, multiplication etc. I would like to get the report for each test run with pass/fail result.Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way JUnit reports are designed. Each test case (== test method is reported once).

You get separate reports by defining separate methods. You don't need the 'name' of the test case for reporting. The name is purly a human readable name attached to a test class or suite.
This is how to write your test cases:

```
public void testAddition {
  addition(table, expectedResult);
}
public void testMultiplication {
  multiplication(table, expectedResult);
}
public void testSubstraction {
  substraction(table, expectedResult);
}
```